# Vapor 3 - Returning a different Future when a search fails?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm using Vapor 3 and linking to a FoundationDB database, so Im not using Fluent. I have a method that searches for a record, but it will obviously crash if it does not return a record (because I force unwrap the value).

I want to guard the reading from the database and return a response if no record is found. This will however not be the record as was expected in the Future. I was thinking that I should return a different response, but am unsure how to change the result that is expected.

```
//creates a specific country
func getCountry( req: Request) throws -> Future<Country> {
    // get Country name from get parameter string
    let countryString = try req.parameters.next(String.self)


    // get record from Database. This could fail and so needs to be guarded. What response should be returned as the Future requires a Country datatype?

       let record =  FDBConnector().getRecord(path: Subspace("iVendor").subspace(["Countries", countryString]))



    let newCountry = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: record!)
    // return Country Struct
    return Future.map(on: req) {return newCountry }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

First, if you throw an error from the method:

```
guard let record =  FDBConnector().getRecord(path: Subspace("iVendor").subspace(["Countries", countryString])) else {
    throw Abort(.notFound, reason: "No country found with name \(countryString)")
}
```

The error will get converted to a 404 (Not Found) response with `"No country found with name \(countryString)"` as the error message.

If you want more control over the resulting response, you can change the route hander's return type to `Future<Response>`. You can then encode the `Country` object to the response or create a custom error response. This method does take some extra work though.

```
let response = Response(using: req)
guard let record =  FDBConnector().getRecord(path: Subspace("iVendor").subspace(["Countries", countryString])) else {
    try response.content.encode(["message": "Country not found"])
    response.http.status = .notFound
    return response
}

try response.content.encode(record)
return response
```

Note that you will have to conform `Country` to `Content` if you want that snippet to work.